# How can I create a JSONObject column using Room?

Tags: java, android, json, android-room

I have a database on the server (MySql) and a local database (Room), In the database on the server there is a table called countries and inside that table, There is a column called countryName and the type of that column is JSON, As you can see in the image below.

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8jvX.png)

The content inside countryName is JSONObject

**The Table**

```
@Entity(tableName = "Countries")
public class Country {
    
    private JSONObject countryName;

    public Country(JSONObject countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public JSONObject getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    
}
```

**Error**

```
Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
```

How can I create a JSONObject column using Room?

Comment: Json object cannot be saved in to the Room, Converting to String and saving to the room and Converting again while retrieving the String, will do the work.

Comment: @RaBaKa78 I know that, But it's better to store it like the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Java Version:**

```
  class MyConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    public String jsonToString(JSONObject data){
        return data.toString();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public JSONObject stringToJson(json: JSONObject){
      return JSONObject(json);
     }
}
```

And use this above your Database:

```
@Database(entities = ....)
@TypeConverters({MyConverters.class})
public abstract class RoomDb extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract UserDao userDao();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Room doesn't support saving JSON data type directly, but you can write a  `@TypeConverter`

### Using type converter:

```
internal class MyConverters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun jsonToString(data: JSONObject): String = data.toString()

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToJson(json: JSONObject): JSONObject = JSONObject(json)
}
```

And use this above your `Dao`:

```
@Dao
@TypeConverters(MyConverters::class)
internal abstract class MyDao
...
```

Comment: Java not Kotlin

Comment: Well it was pretty much the same, but anyways the answer is posted by RaBaKa